# exec /sbin/tini: exec format error running Meilisearch on AWS App Runner

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, meilisearch, amazon-app-runner

I am trying to run the docker image `getmeili/meilisearch:latest` on AWS App Runner, however getting `PM exec /sbin/tini: exec format error`.

Running the same image on AWS Container Service works fine. I have tried to change the build machine, ensuring the image is `amd64` to no avail.

The same image that works on ECS is deployed from the Elastic Container Registry (ECR) is deployed on App Runner by creating a new App Runner, choosing from "Image".

Comment: It's somewhat important to know the *how* of the deployment of the image in order to figure out what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is from building on an M1 Mac. The following worked for me:

1. Delete the ECR Repo (even when there are no images in it, there seems to be some caching where layers are not uploaded afresh each time you push).
2. Create a new ECR Repo
3. Delete the App Runner
4. Build the image using the `--platform=linux/amd64` flag
5. Push this to the ECR Repo
6. Re-create the AppRunner service